# Find the numpy array elements satisfying the condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want to find the elements satisfying my condition
The codes are as below:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2]])
b = np.array([1, 2])
c = (a == b)
```

The results are

```
[[ True  True]
[ True False]
[ True  True]]
```

But what I want is [True, False, True] or the indices [0, 2].

Although I can achieve this by list comprehension, like

```
c = [all(b==x) for x in a]
```

But I want to find this element in a 3d matrix in the future, like

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2]], 
         [[7, 2], [1, 2], [4, 2]]])
```

I want the index like [[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1]]

How should I achieve this by numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) with `axis`:

#### Code:

```
np.all(a == b, axis=1)
```

#### Test Code:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2]])
b = np.array([1, 2])
c = np.all(a == b, axis=1)
print(c)
```

#### Results:

```
[ True False  True]
```

Comment: It works and works for 3D matrix as well, thanks so much